# Are YouTubers Allowed to Record any Game

Tags: derivative-works, lgpl

For games like minecraft it is released under "LGPL 2.1 or later", does this mean that if you record Minecraft the video must also be released under the LGPL 2.1 or later?

Is a separate license needed or are you allowed to record and publish any game?

Comment: Are you sure that Minecraft is distributed under the terms of the GNU LGPL 2.1 or later?

Comment: This question is too broad. Asking about what the LGPL means for videos of the software being used is one thing, but you can't also ask about all other games in existence in the same question!

Comment: If you want to ask about the legality of recording game play, then [law.se] would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Recording footage of gameplay and releasing it is quite a grey area. For example, Nintendo used YouTube's copyright enforcement system to [claim advertisement revenue from people who recorded videos of their games](http://www.engadget.com/2013/05/16/nintendo-mass-claims-revenue-from-youtube-lets-play-videos/) and Sega used [DMCA takedown notices to remove such videos completely](http://www.tssznews.com/2012/11/27/sega-launches-shining-force-dmca-campaign-on-youtube/). But these only went through YouTube's internal systems of handling copyright violation complaints. I don't know if these were ever challenged in a court of law.